# Use a car as a scooter? 作为代步车?

Tags: mandarin

Google translate tells me that 作为代步车 means "as a scooter".

Is that what it means in this sentence:
我想买一辆二手的马自达作为代步车

Comment: 代步 means to replace walking. Any transportation (including scooters and cars or even airplanes can be a 代步工具). Here, it specifies 代步车, which means a car as transportation (to replace walking). This often depends on context. If you say, 我想买辆摩托车作为代步车, would have the meaning: I'm thinking of buying a motorcycle as transportation.

Answer (score 2):

我想买一辆二手的马自达作为代步车

In the context of this particular sentence, the only way for the sentence to make sense is to translate 代步车 as "transportation", as in:-

"I am thinking of buying a second hand Mazda as transportation",
because 代步 also means "to transport", and I think the 车 is clumsily used because 代步车 could easily be confused with "scooter", the common default meaning.

It is better to say 代步工具 to avoid such confusion.

Comment: Agreed. The original sentence likes saying; "我想买一辆二手**车**作为代步**车**, the second "车" does not make logical sense. Either "工具" or "用" is the normal choice of replacement word.

Comment: Unless the author wants to convey the contemporary, "cool", idea of using the secondhand Mazda for "scootering" around town for leisure fun, rather then as a primary means of everyday commute transportation? Nowadays the Chinese language is heavily influenced by English / European expressions borne out of contemporary culture.

Comment: I wouldn't comment if he says "這一辆二手的马自达是我的代步车", although not perfect, it is acceptable :)

Answer (score 1):

作为 = to be/ as

代步 (replace walking) = for transportation

车 = car

> 我想买一辆二手的马自达作为[**代步**]车

> I want to buy a used Mazda to be my [**transportation**] vehicle

代步 is an adjective for 车

Comment: my personal transportation vehicle is an e-bike. Yes, bicycles and e-bikes are vehicles too